# getSystemService in Robolectric returns object with null Context

Tags: android, robolectric

In my activity's `onCreate` I have:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

When testing the activity with Robolectric I create it with

```
ActivityController<MainActivity> controller = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class);
MainActivity activity = controller.attach().create().get();
```

The `AudioManager` is then created but with `mContext = null` which leads to a `NullPointerException` when calling `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver` on it because that framework method uses the context internally.

Is there any way to make sure the `AudioManager` is created with a working `Context`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I played around with this a bit and I actually think that at the moment the answer for this is **no**, there is no way.

Now, if the purpose is to just avoid the NPE when creating the activity, you might be able to get away with Mocking the AudioManager by doing something like this in your test, for Robolectric versions < 3:

```
    AudioManager mockManager= Mockito.mock(AudioManager.class);
    Application application = (Application) Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getApplicationContext();
    ShadowContextImpl shadowContext = (ShadowContextImpl) Robolectric.shadowOf(application.getBaseContext());
    shadowContext.setSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE, mockManager);
```

Another variant might be to [create your own ShadowAudioManager](http://robolectric.org/custom-shadows/) that either handles `registerMediaButtonEventReceiver` or initialises with the correct context, because the [current one](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowAudioManager.java) does not do that, but I haven't actually tried that.

Comment: There is no **Robolectric.getShadowApplication()**

Comment: There was back in '14 before Robolectric 3.x :) 

There is a later edit to clarify that: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26162823/revisions
Should I make it more prominent?

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid a similar NPE crash I added the

```
 @Config(emulateSdk = 18, shadows = {ShadowAudioManager.class})
```

in the class that contains the test!

Answer (score 3):

With Robolectric 3+ use:

```
AudioManager mockManager= Mockito.mock(AudioManager.class);
Application application = (Application) Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getApplicationContext();
ShadowContextImpl shadowContext = (ShadowContextImpl) Shadows.shadowOf(application.getBaseContext());
shadowContext.setSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE, mockManager);
```

Comment: Not sure how you got that to work but on Robolectric 3.2.2 this implementation doesnt work. For instance Robolectric.getShadowApplication doesnt exist

Comment: Shadows.shadowOf(android.content.Context) also doesn't exist in Robolectric 3.8

Answer (score 1):

I had to simulate the `ConnectivityManager` to return a null `NetworkInfo` object when `getActiveNetworkInfo()` was called, with Roboelectric 4.4 you can do this:

```
val context: Context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
val spiedConnManager = spy(context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) 
                           as ConnectivityManager)
//set the service to return what you want, 
//in my case I set the connectivity manager to return null for activeNetworkInfo
doReturn(null).`when`(spiedConnManager).activeNetworkInfo
val shadowApp: ShadowApplication = shadowOf(context as Application)
//setSystemService is deprecated but I did not found a replacement yet
shadowApp.setSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE, spiedConnManager)
//perform your asserts HERE
```

You can use the same approach for any system service you want

Comment: robolectric docs: Do not depend on "shadowApp.setSystemService" method to override services as it will be removed in a future update. The preferred method is use the shadow of the corresponding service.