# Roboletric returns null Bluetooth Manager

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, robolectric

I have tried to test my application which uses bluetooth using Robollectric. But when I try to get the BluetoothManager I always get null back in Roboletric.

The following is how I'm trying to get the Bluetooth Manager inside my class in Robolectric.

```
final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
```

It feels like I'm missing something simple in the setup for Robolectric? The following is the annontations used to setup the class.

```
@Config(
 sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT
 , manifest = "src\\main\\AndroidManifest.xml"
)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The question and answer are outdated if you use **Robolectric v3.1+**

=========================

**Robolectric** provides a [lot of services from the box](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/76a55f5c9386bbe455ec0f664b288870f507b3cb/robolectric-shadows/shadows-core/src/main/resources/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowContextImpl.java.vm). However, the `BluetoothManager` is not part of it. I think it is because before API18 we used `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()`.

It looks like you're targeting the newest API and "old" way is not your choice. As a workaround for your test you could use approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021305/getsystemservice-in-robolectric-returns-object-with-null-context).

I also created [issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1970) on Robolectric GitHub page

Comment: This is no longer true. Robolectric already supports the Bluetooth Manager now

Comment: Updated answer. Thanks!