# Robolectric: Shadows.shadowOf(Context) method not found

Tags: android, robolectric

I have a custom system service that I am trying to mock and add to the shadow context in Robolectric 3.8.

I am trying to follow this answer: [getSystemService in Robolectric returns object with null Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021305/getsystemservice-in-robolectric-returns-object-with-null-context) but it looks like shadowOf(android.content.Context) has been deprecated but I can find no mention of it in http://robolectric.org/migrating/

```
MyService myServiceMock = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
Application application = (Application) ShadowApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
ShadowContextImpl shadowContext = (ShadowContextImpl) Shadows.shadowOf(application.getBaseContext());
shadowContext.setSystemService(Context.MY_SERVICE, myServiceMock);
```

How do I mock/ shadow a system service in Robolectric 3.8?

Answer (score 3):

```
ShadowContextImpl shadowContext = Shadow.extract(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getBaseContext());
shadowContext.setSystemService(key, service);
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer . Code only answer is only meant to copy-Paste its not helpful.

Comment: more info needed, like, you know, what your fields are? That said flagging as it's a poor answer.